# How to Push out OneDrive for Business on multiple network computers

Tags: group-policy

I have several network computers that I need to install Microsoft's OneDrive for Business software agent on. It can be downloaded here: http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/2903984

It is an exe so Group Policy won't work, what options do I have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I've found to do it is using some free software called PDQ Deploy, and no I don't work for them:

http://www.adminarsenal.com/pdq-deploy

Create a config.xml file with the following code in it:

```
<Configuration> 
  <Add SourcePath="" OfficeClientEdition="32"> 
   <Product ID="GrooveRetail" > 
     <Language ID="en-us" />      
   </Product> 
  </Add> 
</Configuration>
```

Place this file and the OneDrive install file in the same folder on your network and share it and grant full permissions to "domain users" and "domain computers".

Download and install the free version of PDQ Deploy and create a new package. Under step 1 of the package settings set the install file to the OneDrive exe shared on your network. For example:

```
\\server\share\PDQ Installs\OneDrive\setup.exe
```

...or whatever location you put it in.

This next step is important. Without it the remote installs will take forever, or in most cases not install at all. You need to add the following line to the "Parameters" field in the package setup:

```
/configure config.xml
```

This just tells the package that when it installs OneDrive use the configure option and look to the config.xml file we made earlier. That way the installation will be in silent mode and it will not require user input to continue.

Save the package and deploy it. That's it. If you have trouble setting up PDQ Deploy here's a great intro video from them on YouTube:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1WJArfo95c4